# Does autocommit really solve deadlocks in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

For some context, I am using NiFi with the PostgreSQL JDBC driver where two processors update different columns for same row in a table using different transactions. This often caused deadlocks with errors like *"ERROR: deadlock detected. DETAIL: Process 70725 waits for ShareLock on..."*

These errors are gone once I enabled the `autocommit` option for the JDBC driver session. However, I am not sure if this is the correct way to solve this problem. Am I just being lucky here or just making things worse? Why do I get no errors when using `autocommit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question shows that you have not thought about database transactions in depth. Yes, there will be fewer deadlocks if you never have any transactions that last for more than a single statement (autocommit), although you can also get deadlocks in autocommit mode. But you have transactions for a purpose:

- to make sure that of several data modifications that must be performed together to transfer the database from one consistent state to another, either all or none of them are executed
- to prevent concurrent sessions from seeing the effects of partial data modifications

You should design your transactions by identifying which data modifications must be in a common transaction to ensure data integrity. Then make your transactions no longer than is necessary to guarantee data integrity. Never, ever perform an activity that could take a longer time while you have an open database transaction. These steps will ensure that you have no more deadlocks than necessary.

Comment: Thanks! You are right that I have an incorrect design. Just to make sure I am getting this right; I am actually doing batch updates so does setting autocommit essentially invalidates this and commits each update individually and this is why I am not getting errors?

Comment: Alright, as you suggested I was also not "thinking about database transactions in depth" and had some misconceptions. Reading the source code of NiFi I now have answer to my comment (which did not make sense) :) Thanks for the enlightenment.